# What is the largest known prime gap, and why is there so much conflicting information??

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I find consistently conflicting information online.

On the one hand there's all these reports of the largest prime gap between all numbers proven to be < 246.

On the other hand, I read reports of the largest known prime number gap being 1476.

On the other hand, I find all kind of different reports, such as this one: http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/gaps.html where there are many prime numbers with gaps > 246.

What am I failing to understand?

Thanks!

EDIT: There's many good answers on this page. Thanks so much you guys! I only chose dalastboss's because I found it easiest to grasp. It was 'dumbed down' enough for me :)

Comment: All of the recent news about prime gaps is trying to find the smallest gap such that there are infinitely many pairs of primes which differ by at most that gap. That is a very different question from just trying to find two primes which differ by some gap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $ n > 1 $, there is a prime gap of size at least $ n $. The results you read probably meant that it's been proven that the least gap which occurs infinitely often is less than 246. That is $ \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; (p_{n+1} - p_n) < 246 $. $\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; (p_{n+1} - p_n) =_? 2$ is the twin prime conjecture.

Answer (score 15):

For every number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that you can think of, I can give you a sequence of $n-1$ consecutive numbers, none of which is prime.

There you go: $n!+2,n!+3,\dots,n!+n$.

So there is no finite bound on the gap between two consecutive primes.

Comment: Slick example, +1

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: Thanks (slick?).

Comment: Impressively smooth. Efficient. (= slick)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: Oh... got it :)

Comment: even more efficient is to use $n\#$ which is $n$ primorial.

Answer (score 2):

User barak manos provides a nice proof for the divergence of the [limit superior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) of the sequence of [prime gaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) $g_n$, where, if $p_k$ is the $k^\text{th}$ prime,

$$g_n = p_{n+1}-p_n$$

Even stronger results have been proven. For example, for any (arbitrarily large if you like) $c \in \mathbb{R}$, there exist infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the [prime gap $g_n$ satisfies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Lower_bounds)

$$g_n > \frac{c\log n \log\log n \log \log\log \log n }{\left(\log\log\log n\right)^2}$$

Comment: In the following blog, Terry Tao announced they had removed one of the $\log\log\log n$ from the denominator.  https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/long-gaps-between-primes/